# Leoxsys USB Wireless Adapter not detected in lspci

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers

I bought a Leoxsys USB Wireless Adapter for my laptop (Kubuntu 15.04) and installed the required drivers. It can detect other wifi devices but I can't create a hotspot using it.

The wireless adapter shows running in -

ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a4:5d:36:66:2b:41  
          inet addr:192.168.159.220  Bcast:192.168.159.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a65d:36ff:fe66:2b41/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:319759 errors:0 dropped:64 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:27494 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:41943024 (41.9 MB)  TX bytes:6915738 (6.9 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1539 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1539 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:159867 (159.8 KB)  TX bytes:159867 (159.8 KB)

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:4c:08:4a:2e  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

But the device can't be detected in -

lspci -nn

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [8086:0154] (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port [8086:0151] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1e10] (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1e12] (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:1e14] (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1e59] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:1e03] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
01:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330] [1002:6660] (rev ff)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
```

The output of sudo lshw -C network is -

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 07
       serial: a4:5d:36:66:2b:41
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=192.168.159.220 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:26 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c3404000-c3404fff memory:c3400000-c3403fff memory:c3410000-c341ffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:2
       logical name: wlan1
       serial: 00:e0:4c:08:4a:2e
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8188eu multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
```

`iw list` does not give any output.

I tried creating hotspot using ap-hotspot but it says -

```
$ sudo ./ap-hotspot start
Your wireless card or driver does not support Access Point mode
```

Answer (score 1):

The wireless adapter is not shown in `lspci`, because it is not connected to PCI bus. It can be shown in `lsusb`.

Not all wireless adapters can be used as a hotspot.

And you can see that "your wireless card or driver does not support Access Point mode".